# Where to get negative sample images for Haar training?

Tags: opencv, training-data, haar-classifier

I need a collection of sample images to train a Haar-based classifier for face detection. I read that a ratio of 2 negative examples for each positive example is acceptable. I searched around the web and found many databases containing positive examples to train my classifier (that is, images that contain faces), however, I can't any database with negative examples. Right now, I have over 18000 positive examples. Where can I find 2000 or more negative examples?

Comment: Could you please try and fix the spelling/grammar issues. As of now, your post is unreadable.

Comment: which word you doesn't understand it ?

Comment: The entire piece, you fixed some spelling errors, but it still is really confusing. Are you asking for how to extract the background? How to find a database of images? How the haar training works to read an image, and how you can generate sample images? Any of these are possible interpretations of your question.

Comment: no I ask where can i find negative image more than 20000
downloading it from google take long time

Comment: just use any images where the object-to-detect isnt present. You can use rotations/scales and subimages of those negative samples too.

Comment: i know any image but i need more than 20000 

any way for download 20000 image from google street ?

Comment: I guess you could take a lot of screenshots... Honestly, without more information I don't know what else to tell you. What you are asking for really is vague. (Maybe checkout MIT, Carnegie, etc. They often have databases of images. [Although not likely 20k, that is a REALLY big amount]. ) You might have to generate them yourself if you need that many.

Comment: The link you provided has roughly 5k negative images, what are you trying to train it to do that you need much more than that?

Comment: i have 15000 positive image so i must have more  than 15000 for negative for this tow days i have now 8000

Comment: You still haven't said what "object" you are training it to find. How are we supposed to suggest the correct database without this information.

Comment: i say its face frontal and profile

Comment: now i just test on 1200 positive image when its on stage 7 
its detect some faces with some false detect but when its be in stage 13 its dosn't detect any thing why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use 
http://tutorial-haartraining.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/data/negatives/

or any other image set that has no objects you need to recognize

NOTE: the number of samples you mention is too big, you don't need so much to obtain high accuracy

Comment: i want to use 30000 image for face detection did thats too big how much must i use ? for best detection 
left side and frontal face

Comment: the original cascade in openCV uses 5000 positive samples - but for front faces only. in your case it might be increased or split in two cascades. which is a better approach - better to check on real data.